# AMD fTPM - What does this firmware option do?

Tags: motherboard, firmware, amd-ryzen, tpm, ftpm

I have ASRock X370 Professional Gaming (AM4) motherbord with Ryzen 7 CPU.
It has network firmware upgrade option, but I had to disable fTPM to enable network flash option.

What exactly is fTPM option? What enabling it does? I've read it's related to Bitlocker, but I have a Bitlocker disk, it works the same with this option disabled or enabled.

Comment: It wasn't really an 'issue' in 2019 but it is a requirement for windows 11 installs, and having it built into the chip means you don't need a 'seperate' TPM chip

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"fTPM" is a type of TPM that's implemented in system firmware instead of using a dedicated chip.

The TPM is a tamper-resistant "secure element" used to protect cryptographic keys (including smart-card private keys and BitLocker credentials). BitLocker mainly uses it for the *system* disk, since the TPM can provide **passwordless** unlocking while still resisting external attacks (i.e. it seals the encryption key with the current system state). Without a TPM, you would have to unlock the system disk using a password, a recovery key, or a USB stick on every reboot.

This doesn't apply so much to *data* disks, since Windows is already fully running once they're accessed, it can provide automatic unlocking without a TPM by simply storing the data disk's password in your Windows account. (And obviously it doesn't affect unlocking *with* a password.)

---

The most likely reasons you need to disable the (f)TPM before upgrading firmware are:

1. System firmware is part of the aforementioned "current system state". If you upgrade it, anything that was previously sealed against it would be unusable; e.g. if you used BitLocker with a TPM, you would need to use the recovery key. Some manufacturers insist that the TPM be manually disabled to serve as a reminder to the user that they'll need other means of unlocking the system disk.
2. It's relatively common practice to force all secrets to be erased before a firmware upgrade can happen, also called "insider attack resistance". Because the fTPM is *part of* system firmware, upgrading it can become a security risk – if the new firmware is buggy or backdoored, it may bypass the protections that were supposed to be provided; e.g. it might conveniently "forget" to check system state before releasing the keys. I don't know if "disabling" fTPM erases its contents, but if it does, it would be a very likely explanation.

Comment: TPM doesn't hold nor "smartcard certificates", nor "BitLocker credentials". Those are just sealed to it or are attested by it.

Comment: You are talking, quoting _"TPM is a tamper-resistant "secure element" used to hold cryptographic keys (including smartcard certificates and BitLocker credentials)"_. Which is outright not true.