# TPM 2.0 module compatible with MSI Z170A SLI Plus

Tags: motherboard, tpm

Am I correct in assuming that the MSI Z170A SLI Plus is incompatible with TPM 2.0 modules?

The MSI website offers two versions of the TPM 2.0: MS-4462 and MS-4136. The pins on the MS-4136 match the TPM header on the MSI Z170A SLI Plus motherboard. However, it says it supports Intel 300 series motherboards. I can find no documentation or item for sale that is explicitly labeled as compatible with the Z170A SLI Plus. The motherboard manual itself says to refer to some other manual which I cannot find:

[MSI Z170A SLI Plus motherboard manual reference to TPM module connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9VBj.png)

> This connector is for TPM (Trusted Platform Module). Please refer to
> the TPM security platform manual for more details and usages.

Comment: Instead of attempting to determine if your motherboard is or isn't compatible with a specific external TPM 2.0 device can you tell us which processor you have?  [Most modern Intel and AMD processors have built-in support for TPM 2.0](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007452/intel-nuc.html)

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing of TPM until the Windows 11 health check said my computer was incompatible. I have an i7 6700K CPU.

Comment: This isn't a TPM issue. If you upgrade your bios a TPM will be added. I think it's because the processor isn't supported....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that the MSI Z170A SLI Plus is incompatible with TPM 2.0 modules?

It does not matter if your motherboard is or isn't compatible.  Your i7 6700K is already compatible since it supports Intel Platform Trust Technology (Intel PTT)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1411061/amd-ftpm-what-does-this-firmware-option-do)

> That shortfall is changing with firmware-based implementations of TPM. Intel’s PTT was Introduced in 2013 on select fourth-generation Intel Core processors and chipsets, including Intel Haswell ULT multichip packages, as well as on Atom-based, system-on-a-chip solutions like Bay Trail. PTT enables low-cost and low-power devices to support the same root of trust concepts enabled by hardware-based TPM. Furthermore, it supports all of Microsoft’s requirements for firmware Trusted Platform Module (fTPM) 2.0.

All you have to do is enable the feature within your firmware.  This does not require any additional steps other than saving the settings and rebooting your system.  On an MSI motherboard, the option is located within the `Settings\Security\Trusted Computing` panel.

[image: enabling TPM in MSI Click Bios 5]

Source:

- [Intel Platform Trust Technology (PTT): TPM For The Masses](https://www.onlogic.com/company/io-hub/intel-platform-trust-technology-ptt-tpm-for-the-masses/)
- [Windows 11 - Hardware and Software Requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-11/)

> Apparently my i7 6700K is not supported by Windows 11

The list of processors on [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements) page are supposed to be only applicable to system builders.   However, there is no guarantee that once Windows 11 RTM is released, it will run on a system that doesn't have a processor in the list.  Based on the statements by Microsoft, it will be technically possible to install Insider Preview builds of Windows 11, on a system that will not meet the final system requirements of Windows 11.  **If you install a Insider Preview build of Windows 11, on a system that ultimately will be incompatible with Windows 11, you will be forced to downgrade to Windows 11 by performing a clean install.**

The only real new requirement for Windows 11 is it now is incompatible any processor that doesn’t support the 64-bit x86 architecture extension.  They have also additionally are now requiring the system have support for either a hardware TPM 2.0 (dTPM) or support fTPM 2.0 (firmware TPM).  It actuality TPM 1.2 is required, but fTPM has been supported by nearly all of their processor released in the last decade.

> This specification details the processors that can be used with Customer Systems that include Windows Products (including Custom Images). Updates to this specification may be released in the future as requirements change.
> For each listed edition, Company must use only the processors listed, as specified in the tables below.
>
> The requirements below apply whenever the edition below is pre-installed or provided on external media, including as downgrade or down edition software.

Source: [Windows - System Requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements)