# How to find out the reason, why my PC can't run Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-11

Windows 11 requires this features:

- Processor 1 GHz or faster with 2 or more cores on a compatible 64-bit processor or System on a Chip (SoC)
- Memory 4 GB RAM
- Storage 64 GB or larger storage device
- System firmware UEFI, Secure Boot capable
- TPM Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0
- Graphics card DirectX 12 compatible graphics / WDDM 2.x
- Display >9” with HD Resolution (720p)
- Internet connection Microsoft account and internet connectivity required for setup for Windows 11 Home

I have a 15-ay108nh laptop. As far as I know, it supports all the required features. It has 8GB ram, 256GB storage, UEFI support, TPM 2.0 ( I enabled it in the BIOS ), DirectX 12 compatible graphics / WDDM 2.x, and 1080p screen.

I installed the [health check app](https://aka.ms/GetPCHealthCheckApp), but for some reason, I get this result:

[image]

How is it possible to find out exactly, why it fails?

---

[WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11) gives me this result:

[image: WhyNotWin11]

Comment: tpm.msc is a much better way to confirm if TPM's working. My system had discrete as the default, and setting it to the one on my processor was needed. That seems to be the main source of problems for most

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my computer run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a 15-ay108nh laptop. As far as I know, it supports all the required features.

You have an i5-7200U that is not on the list of supported Intel processors, so your system does not meet the [minimum system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications) to run Windows 11, so the tool indicates your system isn’t compatible[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1411061/amd-ftpm-what-does-this-firmware-option-do)

Microsoft has indicated that not the Insider Preview will enforce all the requirements builds of Windows 11.  However, they have stated that if you upgrade your system to one of these builds and ultimately do not satisfy the system requirements for Windows 11, it will be forcefully downgraded to Windows 10.  I have provided a table that explains the Windows 11 Insider Preview compatibility [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1658777/will-tpm-and-secure-boot-complicate-hardware-upgrades-and-changes/1658781?noredirect=1#comment2540073_1658781).

Source: [Windows 11 Supported Intel Processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors)

Your system could also be failing the requirement for Secure Boot if it’s not enabled.  It would be best if you didn’t consider the requirements for Windows 11 to be finalized until Windows 11 is released later this year.

As already indicated, if for some reason you have a functional dTPM but it’s 1.2 instead of the disabled fTPM that your processor supports through Intel  PTT, that also could be a reason.

Since I see many questions, using this as a duplicate [WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11) appears to be more information today than the Microsoft tool.

Comment: I can confirm that, if and only if you meet all the requirements, the tool actually does indicate your system is compatible.  The table provided by Microsoft gives more insight how the compatibility check for the final build will work.

Comment: @nepdev The "hard floor" requirements are the minimum requirements for installing Windows 11. If your spec is below those then you will be blocked from upgrading. The "soft floor" requirements are those which, if you're below, Microsoft will recommend that you don't upgrade - but will not block you from doing so.

Comment: @Ramhound The supported processors (Intel) are 8th gen onwards. If someone has a 6th Gen Core i7, this health app is basically going to say sorry, no luck, right? Mine is showing I can't install Windows 11 whilst I have TPM 2.0 and SecureBoot enabled.

Comment: @ZainAlly - Yes; However, the processor is a low floor requirement, which means it will be able to run Windows 11.  I provided a table that outlines how that will be possible.  The Microsoft tool today indicates systems that don’t meet both the hard and low floor requirements as not being compatible.  Microsoft has indicated their tool will be updated in the next few weeks.