# Does Windows 11 need Secure Boot and TPM to be present and enabled, to run?

Tags: windows-11

[Microsoft's statement on Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications) lists as "System Requirements":

> **System Requirements:**
>
> **These are the basic requirements for installing Windows 11 on a PC**. If your device does not meet these requirements, you may not be able to install Windows 11 on your device..
>
> ....
>
> **System firmware:** Secure Boot capable
>
> **TPM:** Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0
>
> ....

Does this mean Windows 11 can't be used unless these are present and enabled?

Comment: Yes, a PC that does not meet these conditions will not run Windows 11.

Comment: That would be really strange because a large number of sold desktop PCs do not have a TPM. Only desktop PCs from large manufacturer focused on business customers contain a TPM.

Comment: This remains opinion and speculation until Windows 11 is released but so far Microsoft has been pretty clear about Secure Boot and TPM 2  . My Desktop here (4 years old Windows 10 preloaded) does not have TPM (will be in Device Manager if it exists).

Comment: Fwiw as an aside, my personal _suspicion_ is that there's so sizeable a user base that would reject if so, that if it is a requirement, someone will create a workaround mod. Similar to how Windows 10 was announced as not running on CPUs before Kaby Lake, and there's a community workaround on gitbub for that too. But the ideal answer is to find if its required or not, and not guess, guesses don't mean anything really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the reason, why my PC can't run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1658900/how-to-find-out-the-reason-why-my-pc-cant-run-windows-11)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see the error I got when trying to install W11 the other day

[image]